# Pasting different text on each Ctrl + V

Tags: text, copy, clipboard, paste

sorry for my english.
Do You know any software/web addon which allows user to paste different line from .txt file on each hit of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>? For expample, I have a file:

```
Jack
Morrison
25
5
1987
```

And after copying the whole file, I want to paste "Jack" at first hit of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, "Morrison" at second and so on. Is it even possible?

Comment: Does this mean that you want to paste successive lines of a file like this into another application? For instance, you might want to paste Jack into a field in a web form, then move to the next field and paste Morrison, and so on.

Comment: Voted to close, it belongs on SuperUser.  Ask it there, as there IS an answer but it's not a programming question.